# How do I `install_requires` a bdist package uploaded to PyPI?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, setuptools

I have a Python package that depends on an executable. Since the executable takes a rather long time to build, I'd like to use `bdist` to distribute it through my company's internal PyPI index. I need it on both macOS and Linux.

My `setup.py` works fine on both operating systems. After running `python setup.py bdist upload -r private-pypi`, the index has the two following packages:

- foo-0.0.1.linux-x86_64.tar.gz
- foo-0.0.1.macosx-10.12-intel.tar.gz

However, I'm running into issues specifying the `foo` package as an `install_requires` requirement in other projects. I have another `bar` package that needs it. I have the following requirement for it (in both `setup.py` and a `requirements.txt` file):

```
foo>=0.0.1,==0.*
```

We have several other packages and this requirement format has worked for all of them, but not this one. The error that I get is:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement `foo==0.*,>=0.0.1` (from `bar==1.6.12`) (from versions: `0.0.1.linux-x86_64`, `0.0.1.macosx-10.12-intel`)
>   No matching distribution found for `foo==0.*,>=0.0.1` (from `bar==1.6.12`)

I get this error even on the *same machines* that built the packages that have been uploaded to PyPI.

In this case, the `bar` package is installed with `pip install --upgrade /path/to/bar` (and `.pypirc` is configured to look at our internal PyPI index), but it's also available on the same private PyPI index. Although I haven't tried just `pip install`ing it from there, I suspect that I would get the same error.

AFAIK, this is our only package that is distributed as a `bdist` instead of an `sdist`. Source distributions don't have a platform appended to their version number (it'd be `-0.0.1.tar.gz` instead of `-0.0.1.linux-x86_64.tar.gz`), so the problem is almost certainly there.

That still leaves me at loss for a solution. I'm baffled that `bdist` made a package version that `pip` can't seem to parse.

My goal is to get this package on PyPI with the executable included, and then be able to download it with clients while still constraining the version. How should I be doing this instead?

Comment: I'd suggest `bdist_wheel` instead of `bdist`, afaik no modern tool will install from the bdist tar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `bdist_wheel` appears to have solved the problem.